# Pytractor not importing Firefox

Tags: python, angularjs, firefox, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to use pytractor.

When I write import statement
from pytractor.webdriver import Firefox

Firefox is not referenced-not found. Neither Chrome.

However, pytractor instructions and example clearly have no problem importing 
Firefox: 
[readme file](https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor/blob/master/README.rst)

Anybody has solved this?
(I read the pytractor is not actively maintained, however last activity on its Github page is currently 6 days old so I guess it is maintained.)
[example](https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor/blob/master/src/pytractor/tests/functional/test_webdriver.py)

UPDATE: 
FF was underlined with red squiggly line in Pycharm but the code still works. I just didn't run it. It's Pycharm's error checking that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have any issues with that. Installed it from github:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor
```

And imported in the Python shell:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: from pytractor.webdriver import Firefox  
In [2]:
```

Make sure you don't have your script named `pytractor`.

Comment: Tanks. Good to know it works for you. I imported from pytractor.webdriver import Firefox in REPL and then dir(Firefox) and it showed all the methods on FF.

Comment: Pycharm underlines Firefox with red squiggly line so I thought it doesn't wotk. Then I ran the program and it works. It must be Pycharm confusing error higlighting.

Comment: @user1552294 got it, make sure you've got the project interpreter with `pytractor` installed.